# PHP / Javascript - Nulling referer

Tags: php, javascript, null

I'm looking for a simple script that I can use to null the referer

An example would be:

http://www.refnull.com/

Does anybody know how to null the referer in php or javascript?  I don't mind either way, preferable not using any database.

So they go to www.examplesite.com/link.php?http://whateverlinktonull.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that `refnull.com` does it is the following (you can figure this out by using a tool like `Fiddler2` for windows):

---

**Request 1 content**:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.refnull.com/?http://www.whatismyreferer.com/&attempt=1">
```

..which redirects you to request 2:

---

**Request 2 content**:

```
<script>
    function go(){
        window.frames[0].document.body.innerHTML='<form target="_parent" method="post" action="http://www.refnull.com/?http://www.whatismyreferer.com/&attempt=1&attempt=2"></form>';
        window.frames[0].document.forms[0].submit()
    }   
</script>
<iframe onload="window.setTimeout('go()', 99)" src="about:blank" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
```

..which redirects to request 3:

---

**Request 3 "content"**:

A `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` header that can be done with the following PHP:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
header("Location: http://www.whatismyreferer.com/");
die();
```

..which redirects you to the external site.

Answer (score 1):

Use [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). The referer is set by the browser but this usually worked fine for me.

You can either spit it out in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">
```

or you can set the http header directly:

```
Refresh: 0;URL='http://example.com/'
```